# конвертация с бинарного в hex

Tags: python

Ребята не могу справиться нужна ваша помощь нужно правильно подать данные на

Вопрос такой: Как данные которые выводятся в формате 10101010 `print(''.join(msp))`.
Конвертировать в hex и отправить на генерацию сюда `if Key.from_hex('0' + 'b' + ''.join(msp))`

[image: работа выглядит так]

```
from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations, partitions
from bit import Key

MAX = 50  # (all counts < MAX)
elements = "100010101010"
N = len(elements)
M = 63  # output length


def dict_to_list(dct, N):
    ret = [0] * N
    j = 0
    for k, v in dct.items():
        ret[j:j + v] = [k] * v
        j += v
    return ret


for dct in partitions(M, k=MAX - 1, m=N):
    lst = dict_to_list(dct, N)
    for part in multiset_permutations(lst):
        el = ''.join(n * v for n, v in zip(part, elements))
        for msp in multiset_permutations(el):
            print(''.join(msp))
            #print ((heximal + '\n')+''+(key.address + '\n' + '\n'))
            if Key.from_hex('0' + 'b' + ''.join(msp)).address.startswith('1TEST'):
                print (('0' + 'b' + ''.join(msp) + '\n')+''+(Key.from_hex('0' + 'b' + ''.join(msp)).address + '\n' + '\n'))
                f1 = open('1test.txt', 'a')
                f1.write(('key : ' + '0' + 'b' + ''.join(msp) + "\n")+''+str('Address : ' + Key.from_hex('0' + 'b' + ''.join(msp)).address) + "\n" + "\n")
                f1.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

если это делается не для образовательных целей, то преобразование между форматами можно проводить штатными методами

```
binary_str = '1010101011'
int_value = int(binary_str, 2)
hex_value = hex(int_value)

print(binary_str, int_value, hex_value)
```

**P.S.** было бы не плохо увидеть пример входных и ожидаемых выходных данных, что бы можно было проверить весь код

Comment: добавь пример входных данных в вопрос и ожидаемый результат